# can we use shoutem and native base at same time without loosing performance

Tags: react-native, native-base, shoutem

can I use native base component along with shoutem animation  , I have , without speeding down the application ? (I don't know how to compare the performance of different code in react native so any suggestion in this matter could help me a lot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it. @shoutem/animation should not impact your app's performance. It just wraps React Native Animated API and exposes it in a declarative way.